# The top navigation menu dropdowns is hidden below the webpage content, and i want to fix content position on different screen sizes

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

```css
 
  
    body{
      background-color: white;
      height: 100%;
    }
    html, body {height: 100%; min-height: 100%} 

    .active {
      background-color: white; /* Add an active/current color */
    } 
    hr{
      background-color: #116466;
    }
    img.avatar {
      width: 40px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      float:left;
      padding: 12px;
      height: 40px;
    }
    .imgcontainer {
      text-align: center;
      margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
    }

    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;

    }

    li {
      float: left;
      width:14%;
      font-size: 18px;
      color:#116466;
    }

    li a, .dropbtn {
      display: inline-block;
      color: #116466;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
      background-color: #116466;
      color: white;
    }

    li.dropdown {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    li p{
       color: #116466;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: white;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
      color: #116466;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #116466;
      color: white; 
    }

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
    }
    .chip {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 0 25px;
      height: 50px;
      font-size: 16px;
      line-height: 50px;
      border-radius: 25px;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }

    .chip img {
      float: left;
      margin: 0 10px 0 -25px;
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }


    .dropdown-img {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown-content-img {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      z-index: 1;

    }

    .dropdown-img:hover .dropdown-content-img {
      display: block;
      background-color: #116466;
      color: white;
    }


    .card {
      background-color: #116466;
      color: white;
      max-width: 300px;
      margin: auto;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: arial;
    }

    .title {
      color: white;
      font-size: 18px;
    }

    form.example input[type=text] {
      padding: 3px;
      font-size: 14px;
      border: 1px solid grey;
      float: left;
      width: 80%;
      background: #f1f1f1;
      margin-top: 10px;

      }

    form.example button {
      float: left;
      width:15%;
      padding: 6px;
      background: #2196F3;
      color: white;
      font-size: 10px;
      border: 1px solid grey;
      border-left: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      margin-top: 10px;

    }
    .example{
      align-items: right;
      padding-left: 50px;

    }
    form.example button:hover {
      background: #0b7dda;
    }

    form.example::after {
      content: "";
      clear: both;
      display: table;
    }

      /* Style the sidebar - fixed full height */
    .sidebar {
      height: 100%;
      width: 15%;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      padding-top: 16px;
      margin-top: 85px;
    }

    /* Style sidebar links */
    .sidebar a {
      padding: 6px 10px 30px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #116466;
      display: block;
    }

    /* Style links on mouse-over */
    .sidebar a:hover {
      color: white;
      background-color: #116466;
    }

    /* Style the main content */
    .main {
      margin-left: 3%; /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
      padding: 0px 10px;
    }

    /* Add media queries for small screens (when the height of the screen is less than 450px, add a smaller padding and font-size) */
    @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
      .sidebar {padding-top: 15px;}
      .sidebar a {font-size: 18px;}
    }

    .vertical-line {
      border-left: 2px solid green ;
      height: 150%;
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -35%;
      margin-top: 6%;
      top: 0;
      border-color: #116466;
    }

    .row{
      margin-left: 9%;
      margin-right: -9.2%;
      height: 300px;
      margin-top: 5%;
      margin-bottom: 5%;
    }
    #employees-profile-companies{
      margin-right: 1%;
      column-count: 2; 
    }
    #employees-profile{
      height: 100%;
    }
    #employees{
      border: 1px solid black;
      height: 49%;
      margin-bottom: 1%;
    }
    #profile{
        border: 1px solid black;
        height: 49%;
        margin-top: 1%;
    }
    #companies{
        border: 1px solid black;
        height: 100%;
    }
    #reports{
        border: 1px solid black;
        margin-left: 1%;
    }
    #projects{
      border: 1px solid black;
      margin-right: 1%;
    }
    #tasks{
      border: 1px solid black;
      margin-left: 1%;
    }
    #calendar{
      border: 1px solid black;
      margin-right: 1%;
    }
    #employeestructure{
      border: 1px solid black;
      margin-left: 1%;
    }
    table, th, td{
      /* border: 1px solid black; */
      border-collapse: collapse;
      text-align: center;

    }
    table{
      width: 100%;
      /* height:50%; */
    }
    tr:nth-child(even){
      background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }
    th{
      background-color:  #116466;
      color:white;
    }
    td{
      padding: 1%;
    }
    #linkToCompanies{
      color:#116466;
    }
    .flip-card {
      background-color: transparent;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
      perspective: 1000px; /* Remove this if you don't want the 3D effect */
    }

    /* This container is needed to position the front and back side */
    .flip-card-inner {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      transition: transform 0.8s;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
    }

    /* Do an horizontal flip when you move the mouse over the flip box container */
    .flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }

    /* Position the front and back side */
    .flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      backface-visibility: hidden;
    }
    /* Style the front side (fallback if image is missing) */
    .flip-card-front {
      background-color: white;
      color: black;
    }
    /* Style the back side */
    .flip-card-back {
      background-color: white;
      color: black;
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
      text-align: center;
    } 
    input[type="checkbox"]{
     position: absolute;
     right: 9000px;
    }
    input[type="checkbox"] + .label-text:before{
     content: "\f096";
     font-family: "FontAwesome";
     /* speak: none; */
     font-style: normal;
     font-weight: normal;
     font-variant: normal;
     text-transform: none;
     line-height: 1;
     -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
     width: 1em;
     display: inline-block;
     margin-right: 5px;
    }
    input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .label-text:before{
     content: "\f14a";
     color: #116466;
     animation: effect 250ms ease-in;
    }

    input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + .label-text{
     color: #aaa;
    }

    input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + .label-text:before{
     content: "\f0c8";
     color: #ccc;
    }
    label{
     position: relative;
     cursor: pointer;
     color: black;
     font-size: 19px;
    }
    #tasksList{
      margin-left: -3.5%;
      margin-top: 3%;
    }

    /* Employee button */
     .btn{
       background-color: #116466; /* Blue background */
      border: none; /* Remove borders */
      color: white; /* White text */
      padding: 12px 16px; /* Some padding */
      font-size: 16px; /* Set a font size */
      cursor: pointer; /* Mouse pointer on hover */

    }
    /* Darker background on mouse-over */
    .btn:hover {
      background-color: RoyalBlue;
    } 
    h3{
      background-color: #116466;
      margin-left: 2%;
      margin-top: 2%;
      color: white;
      font-size: 22px;
    }
    h5{
      text-align: center;
      padding: 7%;

    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Dashboard</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesdb.css"> 
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">  
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      </head>
    <style>
    </style>
    <body>
     
     <ul>
      <li style="padding: none;">
        <div class="chip dropdown" style="margin-left: 2%; margin-right: 2%;">
            <img src="img_avatar3.png" alt="Person" width="96" height="96">John Doe
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <div class="card" style="margin-left: 5%;">
                <img src="img_avatar3.png" alt="John" style="width: 75%; margin-left: 30px;">
                <h1>John Doe</h1>
                <p class="title">CEO & Founder, Example</p>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
       </li>
        <li style="margin-left: -50px;">
         <a class="active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown" style="margin-left: -50px;"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn"><i class="fas fa-bell"></i> Notifications</a>
         <div class="dropdown-content">
          <p>-Select-</p>
              <a href="#">Recent Notifications</a>
          <a href="#">View All Notifications</a>
         </div>
        </li> 
        <li class="dropdown" ><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn"><i class="fa fa-tasks"></i> Tasks</a>
         <div class="dropdown-content">
          <p>-Select-</p>
          <a href="#">Active Tasks</a>
          <a href="#">View All Tasks</a>
         </div>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"  style="margin-left: -50px;"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i> Profile</a>
         <div class="dropdown-content">
              <p>-Select-</p>
          <a href="#">Settings</a>
          <a href="#">Change Password</a>
          <a href="#">Log Out</a>
         </div>
        </li>
          <li>
            <form class="example" action="/action_page.php" style="max-width:300px">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search2">
              <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
            </form>
          </li>
      </ul>
     <hr>      

    <div class="sidebar">
      <a href="dashboard.html"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard</a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-users"></i> Employees</a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Access Rights</a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-gavel"></i> Equipment</a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-building"></i> Companies</a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> Projects</a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-handshake-o"></i> Proposals</a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-line-chart"></i> Reports</a>
    </div>
    <div class="vertical-line"></div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col center-split" id="employees-profile-companies">
          <div id="employees-profile">   
            <div id="employees">
              <button class="btn" style="margin-left: 35%; margin-top: 10%; height: 60px; width:= 50px;"><i class="fas fa-users" style="height: 80px; width:50px;"></i></button>
              <h5>Employees</h5>
            </div>
            <div id="profile">
             <div class="flip-card">
              <div class="flip-card-inner">
               <div class="flip-card-front">
                <img src="img_avatar3.png" alt="Avatar" style="max-width: 50%; max-height: 100%; margin-left: 25%;">
               </div>
               <div class="flip-card-back">
                <h2>Karim Hesham</h2>
                <p>Human Resources Manager</p>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a> 
           <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a> 
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a> 
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a> 
               </div>
              </div>
             </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="companies">
           <h3 style="margin-left: 2%">Companies</h3>
           <hr style="margin-left: 1.5%; margin-right: 1.5%;">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <th>Company</th>
                <th>Industry</th>
                <th>Relation</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Robusta</td>
                <td>Software Development</td>
                <td>Good</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Heineken</td>
                <td>Drinks</td>
                <td>Average</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Unilever</td>
                <td>Consumer Goods</td>
                <td>Poor</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
               <td>Impact BBDO</td>
               <td>Ad Agency</td>
               <td>Excellent</td>
              </tr>
              
            </table>
          </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="col" id="reports">k</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col" id="projects">
         <h3>Projects</h3>
         <hr>
         <table>
          <tr>
           <th>Project</th>
           <th>Deadline</th>
           <th>Progress</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td>HRMang1</td>
           <td>January 2019</td>
           <td><progress value="20" max="100"></progress></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td>HRMang2</td>
           <td>February 2019</td>
           <td><progress value="80" max="100"></progress></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td>HRMang3</td>
           <td>August 2019</td>
           <td><progress value="65" max="100"></progress></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td>HRMang4</td>
           <td>December 2020</td>
           <td><progress value="50" max="100"></progress></td>
          </tr>
         </table>

        </div>
        <div class="col" id="tasks">
          <h3 style="background-color: #116466; margin-top: 2%; color: white;">Tasks</h3>
          <hr>
           <form id="tasksList">
          <table>
           <tr>
              <div class="form-check">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="check"> <span class="label-text">Contact the representative of Unilever</span>
                </label>
              </div>
            </form>
        </tr>
        <tr>
              <div class="form-check">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="check"> <span class="label-text">Interview the new accountant</span>
                </label>
              </div>
        </tr>
        <tr>
              <div class="form-check">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="check"> <span class="label-text">Contact the representative of Unilever</span>
                </label>
              </div>
         </tr>
     </table>
          </form> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col" id="calendar"></div>
        <div class="col-3" id="employeestructure"></div>
      </div>
    </div>



    </body>

    </html>
 Top navigation menu profile card dropdown and menu items dropdown content is hidden below sidebar and main page content, also the page content does not fit well on different screen sizes.
```

I tried changing the overflow and z-index properties in the dropdown content class, but it didn't work and for adjusting page content to be responsive I tried using percentage for width, height, margin, and padding properties so that the page content is relative on different screens.

Comment: There is a lot of code here. Is all of it necessary to reproduce the problem? You are likely to get better answers if you provide a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `overflow:hidden` css applied to UL which causing the issue. check the snippet.

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%
}

.active {
  background-color: white;
  /* Add an active/current color */
}

hr {
  background-color: #116466;
}

img.avatar {
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
  padding: 12px;
  height: 40px;
}

.imgcontainer {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  float: left;
  width: 14%;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #116466;
}

li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #116466;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #116466;
  color: white;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

li p {
  color: #116466;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: #116466;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #116466;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.chip {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 25px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.chip img {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px 0 -25px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.dropdown-img {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content-img {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-img:hover .dropdown-content-img {
  display: block;
  background-color: #116466;
  color: white;
}

.card {
  background-color: #116466;
  color: white;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
}

.title {
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
}

form.example input[type=text] {
  padding: 3px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

form.example button {
  float: left;
  width: 15%;
  padding: 6px;
  background: #2196F3;
  color: white;
  font-size: 10px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-left: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.example {
  align-items: right;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

form.example button:hover {
  background: #0b7dda;
}

form.example::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}


/* Style the sidebar - fixed full height */

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 15%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 16px;
  margin-top: 85px;
}


/* Style sidebar links */

.sidebar a {
  padding: 6px 10px 30px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #116466;
  display: block;
}


/* Style links on mouse-over */

.sidebar a:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: #116466;
}


/* Style the main content */

.main {
  margin-left: 3%;
  /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
  padding: 0px 10px;
}


/* Add media queries for small screens (when the height of the screen is less than 450px, add a smaller padding and font-size) */

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidebar {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidebar a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

.vertical-line {
  border-left: 2px solid green;
  height: 150%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -35%;
  margin-top: 6%;
  top: 0;
  border-color: #116466;
}

.row {
  margin-left: 9%;
  margin-right: -9.2%;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

#employees-profile-companies {
  margin-right: 1%;
  column-count: 2;
}

#employees-profile {
  height: 100%;
}

#employees {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 49%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
}

#profile {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 49%;
  margin-top: 1%;
}

#companies {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100%;
}

#reports {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 1%;
}

#projects {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: 1%;
}

#tasks {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 1%;
}

#calendar {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: 1%;
}

#employeestructure {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 1%;
}

table,
th,
td {
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  /* height:50%; */
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

th {
  background-color: #116466;
  color: white;
}

td {
  padding: 1%;
}

#linkToCompanies {
  color: #116466;
}

.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  perspective: 1000px;
  /* Remove this if you don't want the 3D effect */
}


/* This container is needed to position the front and back side */

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}


/* Do an horizontal flip when you move the mouse over the flip box container */

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


/* Position the front and back side */

.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}


/* Style the front side (fallback if image is missing) */

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}


/* Style the back side */

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  text-align: center;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  right: 9000px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]+.label-text:before {
  content: "\f096";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  /* speak: none; */
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  width: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+.label-text:before {
  content: "\f14a";
  color: #116466;
  animation: effect 250ms ease-in;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:disabled+.label-text {
  color: #aaa;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:disabled+.label-text:before {
  content: "\f0c8";
  color: #ccc;
}

label {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
  font-size: 19px;
}

#tasksList {
  margin-left: -3.5%;
  margin-top: 3%;
}


/* Employee button */

.btn {
  background-color: #116466;
  /* Blue background */
  border: none;
  /* Remove borders */
  color: white;
  /* White text */
  padding: 12px 16px;
  /* Some padding */
  font-size: 16px;
  /* Set a font size */
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Mouse pointer on hover */
}


/* Darker background on mouse-over */

.btn:hover {
  background-color: RoyalBlue;
}

h3 {
  background-color: #116466;
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-top: 2%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 22px;
}

h5 {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 7%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Dashboard</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesdb.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>

</style>

<body>

  <ul>
    <li style="padding: none;">
      <div class="chip dropdown" style="margin-left: 2%; margin-right: 2%;">
        <img src="img_avatar3.png" alt="Person" width="96" height="96">John Doe
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <div class="card" style="margin-left: 5%;">
            <img src="img_avatar3.png" alt="John" style="width: 75%; margin-left: 30px;">
            <h1>John Doe</h1>
            <p class="title">CEO & Founder, Example</p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </li>
    <li style="margin-left: -50px;">
      <a class="active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown" style="margin-left: -50px;"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn"><i class="fas fa-bell"></i> Notifications</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <p>-Select-</p>
        <a href="#">Recent Notifications</a>
        <a href="#">View All Notifications</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn"><i class="fa fa-tasks"></i> Tasks</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <p>-Select-</p>
        <a href="#">Active Tasks</a>
        <a href="#">View All Tasks</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown" style="margin-left: -50px;"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i> Profile</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <p>-Select-</p>
        <a href="#">Settings</a>
        <a href="#">Change Password</a>
        <a href="#">Log Out</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <form class="example" action="/action_page.php" style="max-width:300px">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search2">
        <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
      </form>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <hr>

  <div class="sidebar">
    <a href="dashboard.html"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard</a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-users"></i> Employees</a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Access Rights</a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-gavel"></i> Equipment</a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-building"></i> Companies</a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> Projects</a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-handshake-o"></i> Proposals</a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-line-chart"></i> Reports</a>
  </div>
  <div class="vertical-line"></div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col center-split" id="employees-profile-companies">
        <div id="employees-profile">
          <div id="employees">
            <button class="btn" style="margin-left: 35%; margin-top: 10%; height: 60px; width:= 50px;"><i class="fas fa-users" style="height: 80px; width:50px;"></i></button>
            <h5>Employees</h5>
          </div>
          <div id="profile">
            <div class="flip-card">
              <div class="flip-card-inner">
                <div class="flip-card-front">
                  <img src="img_avatar3.png" alt="Avatar" style="max-width: 50%; max-height: 100%; margin-left: 25%;">
                </div>
                <div class="flip-card-back">
                  <h2>Karim Hesham</h2>
                  <p>Human Resources Manager</p>
                  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a>
                  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="companies">
          <h3 style="margin-left: 2%">Companies</h3>
          <hr style="margin-left: 1.5%; margin-right: 1.5%;">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <th>Company</th>
              <th>Industry</th>
              <th>Relation</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Robusta</td>
              <td>Software Development</td>
              <td>Good</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Heineken</td>
              <td>Drinks</td>
              <td>Average</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Unilever</td>
              <td>Consumer Goods</td>
              <td>Poor</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Impact BBDO</td>
              <td>Ad Agency</td>
              <td>Excellent</td>
            </tr>

          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col" id="reports">k</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col" id="projects">
        <h3>Projects</h3>
        <hr>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Project</th>
            <th>Deadline</th>
            <th>Progress</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>HRMang1</td>
            <td>January 2019</td>
            <td><progress value="20" max="100"></progress></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>HRMang2</td>
            <td>February 2019</td>
            <td><progress value="80" max="100"></progress></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>HRMang3</td>
            <td>August 2019</td>
            <td><progress value="65" max="100"></progress></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>HRMang4</td>
            <td>December 2020</td>
            <td><progress value="50" max="100"></progress></td>
          </tr>
        </table>

      </div>
      <div class="col" id="tasks">
        <h3 style="background-color: #116466; margin-top: 2%; color: white;">Tasks</h3>
        <hr>
        <form id="tasksList">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <div class="form-check">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="check"> <span class="label-text">Contact the representative of Unilever</span>
                </label>
              </div>
        </form>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <div class="form-check">
            <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="check"> <span class="label-text">Interview the new accountant</span>
                </label>
          </div>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <div class="form-check">
            <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="check"> <span class="label-text">Contact the representative of Unilever</span>
                </label>
          </div>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col" id="calendar"></div>
      <div class="col-3" id="employeestructure"></div>
    </div>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
Top navigation menu profile card dropdown and menu items dropdown content is hidden below sidebar and main page content, also the page content does not fit well on different screen sizes.
```